# Tetrahedron vector problem

Tags: geometry, vectors, analytic-geometry, polyhedra

Can you give me hints on how to solve this problem. Prove that three line segments which connect middle of sides of tetrahedron which don't lie on the same plane go through the same point.
How to prove intersection with vectors? I don't even know how to attack this problem.

Comment: Why, that's simple. Say, the vertices of your tetrahedron are $\vec r_1,\vec r_2,\vec r_3,\text{ and }\vec r_4$; now what are the said midpoints?

Comment: Oh so basically I pick a arbitrary point O as on origin and connect radius vectors to vertices? Well midpoints represented with radius vector should be average of those vector radius on those two vertices. I don't where to go from here.

Comment: Good. Now draw those segments between midpoints. What are **their** midpoints (midpoints between midpoints, so to say)?

Comment: Oooohh, I think I get it now. So basically I just have to show that on those segments middle point represented by that vector is actually the same vector for all three? Now I understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The geometry of the problem is not affected by a rotation or by a scaling.
so without loss of generality we can tabulate the four point as:
$$
\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   A  \\
   B  \\
   C  \\
   D  \\
 \end{array} } \right) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   0 & 0 & 0  \\
   2 & 0 & 0  \\
   {2a} & {2b} & 0  \\
   {2c} & {2d} & {2e}  \\
 \end{array} } \right)
$$
The midpoint of the segment $AB$ will be
$$
M_{A\,B}  = \left( {A + B} \right)/2
$$
and analoguously for the remaining 5 combinations.
The three segments that connect the middle of two non-complanary sides will be
those with end points
$$
\left( {M_{A\,X} ,M_{Y\,Z} } \right)
$$
(one end on one of the 3 segments from $A$ to $X$, the other end on the segment connecting the other 2 points)
i.e. those lying on the three lines having parametric equations
$$
M_{A\,X}  + \lambda _X \left( {M_{Y\,Z}  - M_{A\,X} } \right)
$$
and we shall demonstrate that such 3 lines are concurrent:
can you take on from here?

Comment: I'm quite newbie when it comes to Linear Algebra currently, I solved it with elementary methods, but this is a very interesting answer! Thank you!

Comment: @DarkoDekan, glad that it is interesting to you. In fact, not knowing of which math tools you can dispose, I left open the proceeding.